# FMDatabaseQueue dead lock

Tags: ios, database, deadlock

I'm using FMDatabaseQueue and set it as a singleton

```
static FMDatabaseQueue* sharedDatabase;

+ (FMDatabaseQueue *)sharedDatabase
{
  if (sharedDatabase == nil) sharedDatabase = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:DATABASE_PATH];

  return sharedDatabase;
}
```

When I call the inDatabase method like this, it will cause dead lock...

```
[[UserData sharedDatabase] inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
  FMResultSet * rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT id FROM table1"];
  if([rs next]) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotification1 object:aObject userInfo:@{@"key":@1}]; 
  }else{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotification1 object:aObject userInfo:@{@"key":@0}]; 
  }
  [rs close];
}];
```

---

another controller observe the notification

```
- (void)update:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  NSNumber *key = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"key"];
  if ([key isEqual:@1]){
    [[UserData sharedDatabase] inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
      [db executeUpdate:@"UPDATE table1 SET number = ?",1];
    }];
  }
}
```

Anyone has an idea to fix this...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about send the notification after executing the query?

```
__block BOOL result;

[[UserData sharedDatabase] inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
  FMResultSet * rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT id FROM table1"];
  result = ([rs next]) ? YES : NO;
  [rs close];
}];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotification1 object:aObject userInfo:@{@"key":@result}];
```

Comment: Oh! Why didn't I think of that? Thank you!! It fix the problem :D!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what exactly you what to do,but you should know the dataBase can only have a access at the same time .because  FMResultSet is a Singleton，it ONLY keep a access to the Data Base.

So T think you change like this :

```
 [[UserData sharedDatabase] inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db)  
{ 
  int  resultCount = 0
  FMResultSet * rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT id FROM table1"];
  if([rs next]) 
  { 
    resultCount++;
  }
  [rs close];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotification1 object:aObject userInfo:@{@"key":resultCount}];
}];

-(void)update:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  NSNumber *key = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"key"];
 if ([key isEqual:@1])
 {
   [[UserData sharedDatabase] inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db)
   {
     [db executeUpdate:@"UPDATE table1 SET number = ?",1];// ?i think the sql is some thing wrong
   }];
  } 
 }
```